# NER is over writing the custom NERin stanford NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

In the stanford nlp, I used a pattern to match the phone number in regexner. But the NER is over writing it as Number.

If I remove the ner annotation then it is showing as PHONE_NUMBER.
Can any one of you please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my regexner line:

```
^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$  PHONENUMBER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java command:

```
java -Xmx10g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file phone-number-example.txt -outputFormat text -ner.fine.regexner.mapping phone-number-regex.rules
```

example text:

```
I will call him at 555-555-5555
```

format of rules file:

```
555-555-5555    PHONE_NUMBER    NUMBER  1
```

(note the columns are tab delimited)

The fine-grained NER will be applied after the statistical NER.  You can also build a custom `regexner` and run it after the statistical model.  The key is telling it to overwrite the NUMBER tag (which is indicated in the third column).

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$  PHONENUMBER NUMBER
```

this worked the column after the CUSTOM NER column to overwrite