# How to force NER class in Stanford NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

Historically I have used OpenNLP for natural language processing. I decided to give Stanford NLP a try on my latest project and am running into issues with NER. Specifically, when a specific token is processed (`TOKENP` in my example), I would like it to classify this as a type of `TOKENP`.

I have read through the documentation multiple times, read through the response to this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678418/ner-is-over-writing-the-custom-nerin-stanford-nlp), and I cannot get it to reliably be assigned `TOKENP`.

Here is the rules file (`labels.txt`):

```
TOKENP  TOKENP  PERSON  5
```

Here is the input file (`tmp.txt`):

```
Michael Scott Dunder Mifflin TOKENP
```

Here is the command I am using:

```
java -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner' -ner.fine.regexner.mapping labels.txt -outputFormat text -file tmp.txt
```

And here is the output:

```
Tokens:
[Text=Michael CharacterOffsetBegin=0 CharacterOffsetEnd=7 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Michael NamedEntityTag=PERSON]
[Text=Scott CharacterOffsetBegin=8 CharacterOffsetEnd=13 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Scott NamedEntityTag=PERSON]
[Text=Dunder CharacterOffsetBegin=14 CharacterOffsetEnd=20 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Dunder NamedEntityTag=PERSON]
[Text=Mifflin CharacterOffsetBegin=21 CharacterOffsetEnd=28 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Mifflin NamedEntityTag=PERSON]
[Text=TOKENP CharacterOffsetBegin=29 CharacterOffsetEnd=35 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=TOKENP NamedEntityTag=PERSON]

Extracted the following NER entity mentions:
Michael Scott Dunder Mifflin TOKENP PERSON
```

I expect the `TOKENP` as the last token in the input to receive a class of `TOKENP` based on the rules.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the rules system won't break up the entity of "Michael Scott Dunder Mifflin TOKENP".

I could try adding an option that would write a rule based tag over anything under all circumstances (or see if there is already such an option!)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I decided to go with [flashtext](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext) for this particular project. Really all I need is very fast NER with a dictionary.